# How does the 'bumped to the homepage' algorithm work?

Tags: discussion

Occasionally I see the a question marked:

> bumped to the homepage by Community♦ 20 hours ago
>
> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

I'd assumed that it was a randomised algorithm; however recently, ie over the last few weeks, it seems to be following a more distinctive pattern; is it being used as a moderating tool, in the way I've seen moderators also bump questions to the home page?

**Feb 12, 2017** Also, immediately after I posted this question there was an outage for about ten minutes...!

**Feb 17, 2017**  I don't have a link - I didn't keep a log; I wasn't expecting SE to include such a bizarre tactic in its algorithm, so I was inclined to dismiss the evidence of mine own eyes; I'll keep a note from now on: funnily enough, after I edited the post to add more information, there was another 'outage for general maintenance' when I opened up the link you posted; this seems quite strange

**Mar 2, 2017** After I down-voted a post a small message popped up at the side of the vote-box saying "an error occurred"; it was by a poster with which I had a recent spat with; is this another algorithmic "nudge" to suggest "think again", or to discourage voting after having a spat, or simply to discourage voting in a certain direction?

**Mar 2, 2017** Whilst I mulling over how to phrase a comment on a post, interesting enough by the same poster earlier, a small popup box opened over the his icon displaying his bio, which runs as follows "I suffer from circadian rhythm sleep disorder. I don't tell you my timezone so you don't see how bad it is"; now some doctors might describe this about me (but I'd argue about the diagnosis, and in fact no doctor has); this occurred when without me clicking on his profile icon; this seems quite strange; would this be another form of algorithmic "nudging" using "psychological profiling"? Is this form of profiling legal? Could you call this a **"terror tactic"**? It sounds almost **Orwellian**, or perhaps its Post-Owellian; is this part of the "concept of Stack Exchange" or is it still in "development"?

**Mar 2,2017** The bolding tag that I used around **terror tactic** failed, when I looked over what I had written; this seems again strange coincidence given the content of what I am writing which could be construed as an attack on the governing board of Stack Exchange (or its top layer of management); is there an ethics committee that oversees how Stack Exchange uses its social media technology? And if so, are we allowed to know who they are and their background?

Comment: We do not have that power, but perhaps you saw a question that I put a bounty on some weeks ago; this bumps the question. Here is an explanation of the algorithm: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/205264

Comment: @Keelan: it wasn't a question with a bounty on.

Comment: Okay, does any of the reasons given in that post I linked fit? Do you have a link that I can have a look?

Comment: @Keelan: I don't have a link - I didn't keep a log; I wasn't expecting SE to include such a bizarre tactic in its algorithm, so I was inclined to dismiss the evidence of mine own eyes; I'll keep a note from now on: funnily enough, after I edited the post to add more information, there was another 'outage for general maintenance' when I opened up the link you posted; this seems quite strange.

Comment: "terror tactic"? Really? No.